# asp:GridView EmptyData row has wrong colspan

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview

I've got following gridview. There is no error, but when I validate the page with w3c validator and no rows are present, the colspan attribute gets a value of the amount of defined columns in the gridview.
Any chance we can make the gridview remove the colspan attribute when no rows are present?

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gv1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="true" runat="server"
        AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" CssClass="gridview" OnDataBound="gv_DataBound"
        OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="id" CellSpacing="-1" GridLines="None"
        EmptyDataText="no reference substances linked!">
        <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="name" HeaderText="reference substance" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/ReferenceSubstances/{0}.aspx"
                DataTextFormatString="{0}" Target="_self" DataNavigateUrlFields="id" SortExpression="name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="supplier" HeaderText="supplier" SortExpression="supplier" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="supplier_code" HeaderText="supplier code" SortExpression="supplier_code" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="lot" HeaderText="lot" SortExpression="lot" />
        </Columns>
        <PagerStyle CssClass="footer" />
        <PagerTemplate>
            <asp:GridViewPager ID="GridViewPager1" runat="server" />
        </PagerTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add  ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" attribute to show emptydatatext while gridview has no records. Sorry if this is not you are asking

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv1" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" etc
```

Comment: Eventhough, gridview should have code smart enough to remove the colspan attribute when the ShowHeaderWhenEmpty attribute is not set. But this comes close enough. Validation works, which was the main point.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an `EmptyDataTemplate`:

```
<asp:GridView ...
   <EmptyDataTemplate>
      render any markup
   </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Replace `render any markup` wity any w3c compatible markup.

Comment: This yields exactly the same result as using the EmptyDataText attribute. The generated attribute in the resulting table still reads colspan="4" :/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gv1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="true" runat="server"
        AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" CssClass="gridview" OnDataBound="gv_DataBound"
        OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="id" CellSpacing="-1" GridLines="None"
>
     <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    no reference substances linked!
                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="name" HeaderText="reference substance" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/ReferenceSubstances/{0}.aspx"
                DataTextFormatString="{0}" Target="_self" DataNavigateUrlFields="id" SortExpression="name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="supplier" HeaderText="supplier" SortExpression="supplier" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="supplier_code" HeaderText="supplier code" SortExpression="supplier_code" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="lot" HeaderText="lot" SortExpression="lot" />
        </Columns>
        <PagerStyle CssClass="footer" />
        <PagerTemplate>
            <asp:GridViewPager ID="GridViewPager1" runat="server" />
        </PagerTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: This yields exactly the same result as using the EmptyDataText attribute. The generated attribute in the resulting table still reads colspan="4".